# Inject the same Instance of an Interface across my Application?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

In my GWT/GWTP app I have an interface A which I instantiate in my EntryPoint class:

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final A a = GWT.create(A.class);    
}
```

Now I want to inject this interface instance in my Presenters like this:

```
private final A a;


@Inject
public AppPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
        final MyProxy proxy, A a) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);

    this.a = a;
}
```

My idea is to bind the interface in my gin module like:

```
bind(A.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

This would guarantee only one instance. The problem is that an interface has no constructor so this would fail.

**Ho do I instantiate of an interface across my application?**

Comment: Wouldn't GIN automatically use `GWT.create()` so your `bind(A.class).asEagerSingleton()` would work?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer How do I inject A in my EntryPoint Class?

Comment: I have no idea how GWT-Platform works, but assuming you have an instance of your `Ginjector`, then define a method in the `Ginjector` interface that returns `void` and takes your entry-point class as parameter (e.g. `void inject(MyEntryPoint e)`), and call it to inject the entry-point members: `ginjector.inject(this);`

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Could you please post an example for you suggestion?

Comment: @confile: Your example should work just fine. Remove the `final A a = GWT.create(A.class)` in your `onModuleLoad` method (GIN automatically calls GWT.create).

Comment: Doesn't he need to bind the interface to an implementation of the class? Something like `bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class)`. Linked Bindings: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/LinkedBindings